# PHP web application throwing "Too many open files"

Tags: php, apache, exec, fopen, shell-exec

I have a web application which uses php's native functions to write to files e.g. `fopen()`, `fwrite()` after writing to files at the end of the process, I close the file handle by doing `fclose()`.

The web application also uses `exec()` and `shell_exec()` at some places to execute external programs.

This web application is mostly deployed on Linux servers. Recently on a production server, we noted an issue where it was not able to write to a file and was throwing this error:

> "Too many open files"

So my question is: Is it possible that doing the above operations (file writing and executing external commands via PHP) may have caused this and opened too many open files and I am getting this error now?

I have made sure that upon opening the file handles for writing / reading, I close them.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are exceeding the default number of open files. You can increase the maximum number of open files using `ulimit`. Check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) for more details.

Comment: fix the cause not the sympton

Comment: Yes. Fixing the code would help more as if isn't fixed then it will create problems in future also.

Comment: I lately had to open 2000+ files and faced the same problem, so proposed the same solution. But I agree with you, it should done only if required.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible?  Sure.  It's even likely, since ulimit is a per-process limit.

Maybe there's a flow issue that keeps your `fclose` code from running (like an exception, or an else block?).

Do some debugging.  Even something basic like incrementing a counter on fopen() and decrementing it on fclose() would be telling.

Comment: Reviewed the code and made sure `fclose` is not put under any conditional statement and is always called after running the `fopen`. Now debugging the app further to make sure it is also executing as expected.